# Do precalculated parameters aid performance?

Tags: performance, cuda, gpgpu

For instance, if I'm operating on an `m x n` matrix I'll most likely need to pass `m` and `n` to my kernel.

If I also need to know the total number of points `N = m*n`, should I **pass `N` as a parameter** (and consume bandwidth) or **calculate `N` locally in the kernel** for each thread (and consume processing power for lots of duplicate operations even though `N` only really needs calculating once)?

Here, I'm talking kernels which are launched 1000s of times for a collection of large data sets, so really trying to push for performance.

Stride is another example, where you know TBP and BPG before launching the kernel and so can precalculate.

Comment: What happened when you tested it both ways?

Comment: I'm still writing the code ATM, and was hoping for some guidance before finalizing the interface to my kernels, hence the question. Was just wondering if anyone else had timed something like this.

Comment: Why does passing N as a parameter "consume bandwidth"?

Comment: @talonmies - I was thinking that it would consume bandwidth as it would keep having to get passed up from host to device

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer that question you need to know one at least thing.

**What is my limiting factor?**

Basically you have two options:

- your kernel is memory bound - that means you read/write (typically) from/to global memory a lot and/or have small number of computations compared to memory that has been accessed -> you don't have to worry about such optimizations
- your kernel is compute bound - that means r/w traffic is completely hidden by number of computations -> optimization as you described might help but not necessarily

Best option to know which would be to run profiler and run kernel analysis.